# Angular 2-4 Mat-Table row in another component

Tags: angular, angular-material, xmltable, formattable

I would like to know if I can place the mat table rows in another component different from the table component, here is an example:

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="table" matSort>
<user-table-row> </user-table-row>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="profile">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="header-cell"> Profile Type </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user" class="cell"> {{user.profile.type}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="header-cell"> Status </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user" class="cell"> {{user.profile.status}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>


<!-- Header and Row Declarations -->
  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="['createdAt', 'email', 'profile', 'status', 'isApproved', 'actions']" class="header-row"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['createdAt', 'email', 'profile', 'status', 'isApproved', 'actions']" class="row"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

How do I make something like this:

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="table" matSort>
  <user-table-row> </user-table-row>
</mat-table>
```

Is it possible, anyone have done this before?

Comment: Can you setup stackblitz example?

Answer (score 7):

I've created a custom `TableComponent` which uses a `@Directive` with `ng-template` to define the columns. That's pretty flexible and abstracts away all the material stuff. So you can get a common table design all across your application. You just have to define everything once inside this component.

I'll include only the relevant parts.

The `@Directive` is used to get a mapping between `ng-template` and the Material Table column name.

```
@Directive({ selector: 'ng-template[rowColumn]' })
export class TableRowColumnDirective {
    @Input() rowColumn: string;
    constructor(public templateRef : TemplateRef<any>) { }
}
```

The `@Component` fetches all `ng-templates` and build a `Map` to access the `ng-templates` by their column names.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-table',
    templateUrl: './table.component.html'
})
export class TableComponent<T> {
    @ContentChildren(TableRowColumnDirective) rowColumnDirectives: QueryList<TableRowColumnDirective>;

    displayedColumns: ['foo', 'bar'];

    // I use a Map here only, because it's much easier to access the
    // provided ng-templates within table.component.html
    rowColumnTemplates: Map<string, TableRowColumnDirective>;

    ngAfterContentInit() {
        // ArrayUtils.toMap is just a little helper function, which
        // converts an array to a Map. In this case the value of
        // `rowColumn` will become the key of the map
        this.rowColumnTemplates = ArrayUtils.toMap(this.rowColumnDirectives.toArray(), val => val.rowColumn);
    }
}
```

The `@Component`'s HTML simply adds `mat-header-cell` and `mat-cell` using an `*ngFor` loop. The contents of the cells will then be filled with the provided `ng-template`s.

```
<mat-table ...>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let column of displayedColumns" [matColumnDef]="column">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
            HEADER CONTENT
        </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
            <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="rowColumnTemplates.get(column).templateRef" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{$implicit: row}"></ng-container>
        </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

The table can then be used like this:

```
<my-table>
    <!-- rowColumn matches the displayedColumns array -->
    <ng-template rowColumn="foo" let-row>{{row.profile.type}}</ng-template>
    <ng-template rowColumn="bar" let-customRowName>{{row.profile.status}}</ng-template>
</my-table>
```

Now you can add another `@Directive` for the Header Column. In my provided example the Header will always be `HEADER CONTENT`. It's basically just a copy of the `TableRowColumnDirective`.

I know this isn't *exactly* what you were looking for, but I guess you can see how you can inject custom rows into a `mat-table`. Take it as a starting point and I'm sure, you will be able to build a custom solution that fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for your solution Benjamin

Can you think of a better (more Angular like) solution for column-header?

This is what I came up with:

```
<my-table>
  <!-- rowColumn matches the displayedColumns array -->
  <ng-template rowColumn="foo" appColumnHeader="foo##MyCustomFooName" let-row>{{row.profile.type}}</ng-template>
  <ng-template rowColumn="bar" let-customRowName>{{row.profile.status}}</ng-template>
</my-table>
```

TableColmnHeaderDirective:

```
import { Directive, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: 'ng-template[appColumnHeader]',
})
export class TableColumnHeaderDirective implements OnInit {
  @Input() appColumnHeader: string;
  public column: string;
  public header: string;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const splitted = this.appColumnHeader.split('##');
    this.column = splitted[0];
    this.header = splitted[1];
  }
}
```

TableComponen:

```
...
ngAfterContentInit() {
        this.columnHeaders = ArrayHelper.toMap(
          this.columnHeaderDirectives.toArray(),
          (val: TableColumnHeaderDirective) => val.column
        );
      }
...
```

table.html

```
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
    {{columnHeaders.get(column)?.header}}
</mat-header-cell>
```